# SQL triggers, invoke stored proc when an item is inserted/updated/deleted

Tags: sql, triggers

I want to use triggers but is it possible to use a single trigger for insert/update/delete... I have done it for Delete. See below.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[CleanUpDate]
   ON   [dbo].[Marks]
   FOR DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
        DELETE FROM Grades
        FROM Grades
        JOIN deleted ON Grades.ID = deleted.ID
END
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, see the [ALTER TRIGGER reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176072.aspx).

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[CleanUpDate]
   ON   [dbo].[Marks]
   FOR DELETE, UPDATE, INSERT
 AS 
 -- ...
```

Comment: How can I access the object that is being deleted/inserted/updated? do I need to determine the action first??

Comment: @Malcom32: there are two "pseudo-tables" `Inserted` (for the newly inserted values) and `Deleted` available inside your trigger. For UPDATE, you get both tables - `Deleted` has the old values, `Inserted` the new ones. WATCH OUT: those tables will most often contain **multiple rows** since your trigger is fired **once for your batch** - not once for each row

Comment: Your trigger body will have access to two new *virtual* tables: `inserted` and `deleted`: from there you can retrieve the rows to work on and determine the trigger mode.